# CSS drop-down menu not working on hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a working menu, but when I hover over my blog's drop-down menu, it disappears. How can I fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/vkcja/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it:

http://jsfiddle.net/vkcja/4/

I added an onMouseOver and onMouseOut to the menu as well.

Comment: onMouseOut was firing when the user left the button to move to the menu, so I countered it

Answer (score 1):

check this 
http://jsfiddle.net/7MYag/

you need to add onMouseOver and onMouseOut to the li element